# Different value of components from JPanel when coming through different event types

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jpopupmenu

There is one panel which contains 4 components; 1 JLabel, 1 JButton, 1 JTextField and 1 JPopupMenu
There is a method "testMethod()" in which first I get the number of components from the panel and then the type of component(JButton, JLabel etc).

Now there are 2 scenarios occurring when the control flow goes to testMethod():

1. When coming through JButton click event, it shows 4 components on panel and after get all 4 components
2. When coming through JMenuItem click event, it shows 3 components on panel(not getting JPopupMenu) and after only 3 components(not getting JPopupMenu)

I don't get it what is causing this behavior. I searched a lot on the internet and also read JPopupMenu documents but found nothing about this.

Following is the code:
(it is a part of very big code so I put here only that code which is showing the scenario)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TestProject extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestProject frame = new TestProject();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TestProject() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                testMethod();
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnNewButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        // Creating upper level container
        JPopupMenu editMenu = new JPopupMenu("Edit");

        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        item1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        item2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        item2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        // Setting Copy action listener
        item2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                testMethod();
            }
        });

        // Adding the menu items on the popup menu
        editMenu.add(item1);
        editMenu.add(item2);

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                   // Added check to open menu only on left click
                   if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                       editMenu.show(panel, e.getX(), e.getY());
               }               
            });

        // Adding popup menu to the logAreaPanel
        panel.add(editMenu); 

    }

    void testMethod()
    {
        // Here getting number of components of panel
        // When coming through JButton click event, it shows 4 components on panel and after get all 4 components 
        int items = panel.getComponentCount();
        Component c;

        // Getting all the trees one by one and storing their data into StringBuilder
        for(int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < items; loopCounter++)
        {
            // here getting different component types
            // When coming through JMenuItem click event, it shows 3 components on panel(not getting JPopupMenu) and after only 3 components(not getting JPopupMenu)
            c = panel.getComponent(loopCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Once you have displayed your popup menu, you only get 3 components with the button or the popup menu. The issue appears to be that once you display the popup menu, it is no longer contained withing the jpanel.

Comment: Hi @matt thanks for reply. Also looks same to me but I want something concrete whether I am doing something wrong or it is this way only.

Comment: You don't need to add the popup to your panel, [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) You can just add a mouse listener and perform the popup. It seems to handle the mouse listener for you automatically the way your doing it, so I don't know if it is wrong or not. If you read the tutorial, you'll see that the popup has it's own window, which is why it gets removed from the other component upon being displayed.

Comment: @matt thanks for the suggest. Please put you comment as answer as it solved my problem.

Comment: Don't use `panel.add(editMenu)`, use `panel.setComponentPopupMenu(editMenu)` instead

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer i just removed panel.add(editMenu) suggested by matt and now working fine. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the popup to the component. The preferred way is to just use

```
panel.setComponentPopupMenu(editMenu);
```

As per the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup), You could use a MouseListener.

```
//panel.add(editMenu); 
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }

    private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
            editMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
});
```

That way the component count will always be three, because it is never added to the panel.

Comment: Or, preferably, use `panel.setComponentPopupMenu(editMenu);` and let the system deal with it